# get last cart item id woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce on wordpress. This is my code

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
        echo $_product->ID.','; 
} 
?>
```

And this is the result of teh code:

```
1297,1694,1297,3911,4999,
```

How can I get just last id '4999' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing the ids in an array and using the `end()` function would be a solution:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$ids = array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
        $ids[] = $_product->ID; 
} 

echo 'Last item = ' . end($ids);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, really that was solution and I found one more solution for this, here is my code: `<?php
 global $woocommerce;
 $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
 foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
   $_product = $values['data']->post; 
 } 
 echo $_product->ID;
?>`. However thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that you sorted it out! Yeah that's a simple and pretty straight forward one. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even simpler that what Akhilesh proposed - instead of iterating through `$items` array go to the last item there:

```
end($items)['data']->post->ID;
```

I am not sure, but probably you would need PHP 5.3+ for that.